# How to access controller-variables in multiple templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

Hi I´m new to Angular JS, and I am trying to create a "lightbox" by showing or hiding a div that fills the screen. However, the "ng-click" event and the div are on different templates.

**First Template (where the div is supposed to show up):**

```
<body ng-app="portfolio" ng-controller="lightboxController" >

<div ng-show="lightbox" class="lightbox">
    <p ng-click="checkLightbox()">go back</p>

    <p>{{message}}</p>

</div>



        <div class="top-menu">
            <a href="#portfolio" class="top-menu-button">portfolio</a>
            <a href="#about" class="top-menu-button">about</a>
            <a href="#contact" class="top-menu-button">contact</a>
        </div>


        <div id="content-wrapper">
            <div id="main-content">
                <div ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>



</body>
```

**Relevant controller:**

```
app.controller('lightboxController', function($scope) {

    $scope.checkLightbox = function(){

        $scope.lightbox;

        lightbox= !lightbox;

        console.log(lightbox);

    };
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';


});
```

**Second Template (where the ng-click event is):**

```
        <div class="grid">

            <div class="grid-item dreiD video" ng-click="checkLightbox()">
                <img src="data/portfolio/logo-animation/thumb.gif" class="thumb"/>
```

The error message says: *ReferenceError: lightbox is not defined*

Comment: Looks like you need to initialise `lightbox` in your controller and attach it onto the `$scope`

Comment: Ok, thanks. lighbox is now set to false, but how can I attach it to the scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do as below:
Your html look like

```
    <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="lightboxController" >
    <div ng-show="lightbox" class="lightbox">
    <p ng-click="checkLightbox()">go back</p>

    <p>{{message}}</p>

</div>
  <div class="top-menu">
            <a href="#portfolio" class="top-menu-button">portfolio</a>
            <a href="#about" class="top-menu-button">about</a>
            <a href="#contact" class="top-menu-button">contact</a>
        </div>
        <div id="content-wrapper">
            <div id="main-content">
                <div ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item dreiD video" ng-click="checkLightbox()">
      <img src="data/portfolio/logo-animation/thumb.gif" class="thumb"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Angular controller look like:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('lightboxController', function($scope) {

    $scope.checkLightbox = function(){

        $scope.lightbox;

        $scope.lightbox= !$scope.lightbox;

        console.log(lightbox);

    };
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
});
```

You can run this by [clicking here](http://codepen.io/tuhincse24/pen/aZOJgw)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I just had to put "$scope." in front of every use of "lightbox"

Answer (score 0):

Im not really sure what your checkLightbox() method are supposed to do.

But if you want to make this reusable the best solution would be to refactor the checkLightbox functionality into a reusable directive.

Something like this:

```
function checkLightbox() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

             element.on('click', function() {

                 // add your code here
             })
        }
    }
}


app.directive('checkLightbox', checkLightbox);
```

Now you can use this anywhere in your views by adding the `check-lightbox` attribute wherever you want.

```
        <div class="grid">

        <div class="grid-item dreiD video" check-lightbox> 
            <img src="data/portfolio/logo-animation/thumb.gif" class="thumb"/>
```

Comment: checkLightbox() is supposed to toggle lightbox between true and false so that my div is shown or hidden

Answer (score 0):

Declare function or variable in $rootScope whenever you need to use them in any other controller.

Answer (score -1):

Convert your controller into a factory and create the scopes at the $rootScope level:

```
app.factory('lightboxController', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

$rootScope.checkLightbox = function(){

    $rootScope.lightbox;

    lightbox= !lightbox;

    console.log(lightbox);

};
$rootScope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';


}]);
```